# How I can get a high level with this circuit?

Tags: audio, impedance, input

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2olx5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have this circuit.

The MCU on the right select speaker output if I have a low level and if i want audio jack output, i need a high level.

The datasheet give me that exact circuit so by default, if I put nothing on the left side of the circuit, i get low level and i get speaker output.

I want to detect headphone, so with 3 pins (stereo), I can get a switch ... but i don't know i need to add (resistor, capacitor, alim) with this switch to get when a put an audio jack, a HIGH level on the MCU...

I rewrite all my question ... was bad question !

Can you help me ?

[image]

This is the datasheet with the same schema : HP/SPK

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: It's not often I encourage this, but it appears that technology is not treating you well, or the other way around. So maybe it would be best for you to draw a schematic on paper and take a picture of it? As it is now I concur with Andy aka. - You just edited, your input signal is going to ground => makes no sense.

Comment: I made a different schematic, this is better ?

Comment: Is the microcontroller providing the signal or is it the input INTO the microcontroller?

Comment: I need to add a circuit to give a high level to the microcontroller when I detect a headphone ?

Comment: The "circuit need to construct" node on the left is connected to ground. The input node on the right is grounded via R2. Basically, this circuit doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Huh? What the...? The circuit is clear.  But, the thing you are asking about is shorted to ground, and the rest of the question is nonsensical babble.

Comment: I rephrase again ... maybe its better i think ! Srry, its clear in my head, but hard to explain !

Comment: I add the datasheet image with the same schema ... maybe it's better for you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need a high level

The circuit diagram from the datasheet is *wrong*.

As shown, the schematic always shorts that input signal (\$\small HP/\overline{SPK}\$ pin 10 on the IC) to ground and it is impossible for that signal to be "high".

<strike>If you supply a link to the datasheet, it *might* be possible to figure out what circuit they intended to show.</strike> [see update below] I *suspect* the "fix" may simply be to remove the connection shown from that node to ground.

---

Update:

You didn't specify the IC, but after some searching I've found this datasheet mistake matches the [PAM8019 Audio Amplifier from Diodes Inc.](https://www.diodes.com/products/analog/audio/part/PAM8019) (link to [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8019.pdf)). It is *not* an MCU / microcontroller as you stated. That incorrect statement may have confused & frustrated some readers.

Since this mistake is shown in the current public version of the datasheet, I suggest that you contact the manufacturer to find out what they intended to show instead.

---

Update:

Just to add some extra help - I found [this schematic](https://wiki.odroid.com/_media/accessory/stereo_boom_bonnet.pdf) (extract shown below) which uses the PAM8019. It confirms that the \$\small HP/\overline{SPK}\$ signal is just a digital input (switching thresholds are shown in the datasheet). We can see that this signal is being switched by a small MOSFET `Q1`, with a pull-up resistor `R26`, depending on whether a headphone jack is inserted or not:

[image: Extract from the schematic for Odroid Stereo Boom Bonnet]

<sub>Link to the [full schematic for Odroid Stereo Boom Bonnet](https://wiki.odroid.com/_media/accessory/stereo_boom_bonnet.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Ok. Yes i don't explain clearly what was my problem ... thanks for your answer and I finally find that there was a problem in this schematic ... I contact the manufacturer like your propose ! I will post their answer later.

Comment: @user1568445 - FYI I found a device which uses that PAM8019, showing how the \$\small HP/\overline{SPK}\$ signal is used, which may be helpful to you. I have updated my answer with that information.